# Ruby 'require' error: cannot load such file --git (LoadError)

Tags: ruby, git

I've a file, terrabuilder.rb with the following content:

`require "git"`

also tried using

`require_relative '/usr/bin/git'`

The terrabuilder.rb file -> /usr/local/bin, git -> /usr/bin/

If i try to run terrabuilder.rb I get the following error for `require "git"`:

`` terrabuilder master /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- git (LoadError) from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require' from /usr/local/bin/terrabuilder:3:in `<main>' ``

error for `require_relative '/usr/bin/git'`:

`` terrabuilder master    /usr/local/bin/terrabuilder:3:in `require_relative': cannot load such file -- /usr/bin/git (LoadError) from /usr/local/bin/terrabuilder:3:in `<main>' ``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Computers are good at finding things. Very good. So, when a computer tells you that it cannot find something, there is a 90% chance that what you are telling the computer to find doesn't exist. 9% is that you are telling it to look in the wrong place.

So, for `require 'git'`, the first thing you need to check: Is there actually a file named `git.rb` in the current `$LOAD_PATH`? And for `require_relative '/usr/bin/git'`, you need to check the same: Does the file `/usr/bin/git.rb` *actually* exist?